# Cordova PushPlugin + Android 4.4 not working?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

Tried everything I could, but on Android 4.4 I'm not getting a registration ID back from Google Cloud Messaging, while using PushPlugin.

On Android 4.2 everything works fine.
I'm using Cordova 4.2 and PushPlugin 2.4

Tried Cordova 3.6 as well and that didn't work either on Android 4.4.

Has anybody ever had any luck with Android 4.4 and PushPlugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE:***

Solved the problem. It turns out that to use Push Notifications , the device MUST have a Gmail account setup. I was trying this on a newly installed virtual device in Genymotion, without using the Play store, so no Google account was setup yet.